# is there any issues with getting HTML by java with linux?

Tags: java, html, linux, json

I'm trying to get a webpage's HTML using Java. I have the code for doing it and it has been working but some of my clients are having problems and it seems to only be happening on a Linux server. Is there a different way to get HTML with Java for Linux or any issues associated with this?

```
protected static String getWebpageValue(String url, String contains, String endSplit) {
    try {
          URLConnection cnx = new URL(url).openConnection();
          cnx.setRequestProperty("user-agent", "Opera/9.0");
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cnx.getInputStream()));
          String line;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              if (line.contains(contains)) {
                  String[] couple = line.split(contains);

                  for (int i =0; i < couple.length ; i++) {
                      String[] items = couple[i].split(endSplit);
                      line = items[0];
                  }
                  return line;
               }
          }
            reader.close();
        } catch (ConnectException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "URL is down";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "invalid URL";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "IOException";
        }

        return "Encoded String doesn't contain this";
    }
```

Comment: it is throwing the last one "Encoded String doesn't contain this" but the thing is it works on ever other machine but on linux

Comment: http://minecraft-mp.com/api/1/score/
that is the HTML my client wants.

Comment: The more specific you are the more we can help. Knowing the HTML the client is trying to pull data out of is useful, but what are the values of the `contains` and `endSplit` parameters you're using when you have trouble?

Comment: That's not HTML. It's JSON. Your better off parsing the JSON and read the property you're interested in.

Comment: @nlsbshtr i think that you are right. how would i fix this issue